# I want to create Infinite loop in puppeteer-cluster

Tags: node.js, puppeteer-cluster

I want create infinite loop in puppeteer-cluster

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33p9H.png)

but After about 30 seconds, it caused idle 
What should I do?

Comment: `This is my code` There is no code in the question...

Answer (score 1):

There are probably timeout errors being thrown in your code. You have two options:

**Option 1: Listen to the thrown errors**

As you are not listing to `taskerror` events any errors thrown during the process will not be handled.

```js
cluster.on('taskerror', (err, data) => {
      // handle error
});
```

**Option 2: Increase timeout value**

In case your task takes very long, you can increase the `timeout` value:

```js
const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
    // ...
    timeout: 120000 // 2 minutes
});
```

---

In general, you should not create infinite loops inside the `cluster.queue` function. The queue handles that exact task for you. You queue your jobs and then the `cluster.task` function takes care of them. No need to create an infinite loop for tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Thirty seconds is the default time for Timeouts in puppeteer so you may try to disable Timeouts using `page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)` and `page.setDefaultTimeout(0)`

see : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1514
and : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2079